# Chained type-bound procedures in Fortran 2003?

Tags: oop, fortran

Say I am programming a card game in fortran.  I have a card object, with a type-bound procedure "getsuit" and a deck object (consisting of an array of cards) with a type-bound procedure "getcard".

What I'd like is to be able to do something of the form:

```
deck%getcard%getsuit
```

When I do this, however, my compiler informs me that "a function reference cannot be used as the leftmost part-ref of a structure component," even if the function is of type "card."  On the other hand, doing this:

```
card = deck%getcard
card%getsuit
```

works fine.  It seems obnoxious to have to use two lines and an extra variable to accomplish this; is there any way around it?

Answer (score 2):

Depending a little on what your functions do (here assuming that they are more or less pure) you can use user defined operators.

```
the_suit = .SuitOf. (.CardFrom. deck)
```

Answer (score 2):

ISO/IEC 1539-1:2010 a.k.a Fortran 2008 says in section 6.4.2

> R611 *data-ref* **is** *part-ref* [ % *part-ref* ] ...
>    R612 *part-ref* **is** *part-name* [ ( *section-subscript-list* ) ] [ *image-selector* ]
>    C609 (R611) Each *part-name* except the rightmost shall be of derived type
>    C610 (R611) Each *part-name* except the leftmost shall be the name of a component of the declared type of the preceding *part-name*

What this means is that each component of a structure reference must be a data member of the preceding component.  The allowance for `()` in the *part-name* is to allow indexing into array members and does not allow for functions.  That a function returns a derived type does not meet the specification of *part-ref* and so is not valid Fortran and it is right for your compiler to complain.

You can however do this:

```
deck%card(i)%suit
```

assuming card is in array of cards belonging to deck and suit is a type belonging to card.

Comment: I could do that, but I'm trying to keep all the internal variables private and interface only through get and set functions.

Comment: @user3716267 then you might try an approach like IanH has in the other answer.  If you really want high level OO syntax and have no need of Fortrans number crunching, there are better tools you could use.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  Seems the best option is to ditch the proper OOP practice and just let the internal stuff be public.